# How to use Model.query() with promises in SailsJS/Waterline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sails.js, waterline

I'm having issues with Sails.JS 0.9.8. 
I would like to use promises with the Model.query() function (I use sails-mysql adapter).

This code will work :

```
User.findOne({ email: email })
.then(function(user) {
  console.log(user);
});
```

but this one won't

```
User.query("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = ?", [ email ]))
.then(function(err, rows) {
  console.log(rows);
})
```

I get undefined for both 'err' and 'rows'.

Is it just not implemented or I am doing something wrong ?
If not implemented, is there any alternative to use promises with .query() ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can `promisify(User.query)` yourself, just like you'd do for any other callback-based API, like:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
```

....

```
var userQueryAsync = Promise.promisify(User.query);
userQueryAsync("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = ?", [ email ])
.then(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```

Comment: Very nice-- we're now linking here from the reference page from `.query()` in the sails docs.

Comment: I get only
node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

RangeError: Offset is out of bounds

Answer (score 4):

As a hack you can monkeypatch all your models in bootstrap like this

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
    var Promise = require('bluebird');

    Object.keys(sails.models).forEach(function (key) {
        if (sails.models[key].query) {
            sails.models[key].query = Promise.promisify(sails.models[key].query);
        }
    });

    cb();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The `query` method is specific to sails-mysql, and doesn't support deferred objects the way that the more general Waterline adapter methods (e.g. `findOne`, `find`, `create`, etc) do.  You'll have to supply a callback as the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

In case you do not want to use promisify but do want SailsModel.query to
return a promise.

```
/**
 * @param {Model} model - an instance of a sails model
 * @param {string} sql - a sql string
 * @param {*[]} values - used to interpolate the string's ?
 *
 * @returns {Promise} which resolves to the succesfully queried strings
 */
function query(model, sql, values) {
  values = values || [];

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    model.query(sql, values, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      resolve(results);
    });
  });
}

// and use it like this
query(User, 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', [1]).then(console.log);
```