# sails.js .query() Query was empty

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I'm trying to get "Prepared Statement Example" working ( http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query ) but I only get "Error: ER_EMPTY_QUERY: Query was empty"

Here's what I have tried:

```
day: function(req, res, next) {
  Lampo1.query({
    text: 'SELECT id FROM lampo WHERE node = $1',
    values: [ "node1" ]
  }, function(err, lampo1) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
    return res.json(lampo1);
  });
},
```

So I try to make query and add values as parameter, but seems like it won't generate the query at all. Basic example query from the link above works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer from [How to use Model.query() with promises in SailsJS/Waterline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886630/how-to-use-model-query-with-promises-in-sailsjs-waterline)

```
day: function(req, res, next) {
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Lampo1.query("SELECT node FROM lampo1 WHERE id = ?", [ 15 ])
var dayQueryAsync = Promise.promisify(Lampo1.query);
dayQueryAsync("SELECT lampo FROM lampo1 WHERE id = ?", [ 15 ])
.then(function(lampo) {
console.log(lampo);
return res.json(lampo);
});
```