# Bluebird Promises in waterline .native() sailsjs with sails-mongo

Tags: mongodb, promise, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

According to the .native() documentation, the way to use .native() query for sails-mongo is :

```
Pet.native(function(err, collection) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
    collection.find({}, {
        name: true
    }).toArray(function (err, results) {
          if (err) return res.serverError(err);
               return res.ok(results);
       });
});
```

How can I avoid callback here and use promises instead. Note that I have to use aggregate queries, so have to use .native()

Comment: Have you had a look at [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886630/how-to-use-model-query-with-promises-in-sailsjs-waterline)  Open bootstrap.js in config and monkey patch all methods with promise like this

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Object.keys(sails.models).forEach(function (key) {
    if (sails.models[key].query) {
        sails.models[key].query = Promise.promisify(sails.models[key].query);
    }
});

cb();  };
```

On the bonus side you get to use the latest version of bluebird with all models. Hope it helps